# How to make it simpler js with php loop

Tags: php, javascript

```
function displayResult1(szybkosc) {
    var n = value = szybkosc;
    var u = n.split("|")[1]; 
    document.getElementById('result1').innerText = ' '+u;
}

function displayResult2(szybkosc) {
    var n = value = szybkosc;
    var u = n.split("|")[1];
    document.getElementById('result2').innerText = ' '+u;
}
```

The JavaScript code works but I need to do new function for each result, is it anyway to make it quicker?

```
$i = 1;
while($i < 10){
    $result = "result" . $i;
    $displayResult = "displayResult" . $i;
    echo "user number ".$i."
    <input type='radio' name='szybkosc' onclick='$displayResult(this.value)' value='$sp1[id]|1|$row[id]' />
    <input type='radio' name='szybkosc' onclick='$displayResult(this.value)' value='$sp1[id]|3|$row[id]' />
    <span id='$result'></span></br>
    <input type='radio' name='ss' value='$sp1[id]|1|$row[id]' />
    <input type='radio' name='ss' onclick='$displayResult(this.value)' value='$sp1[id]|1|$row[id]' />";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do you have two functions for the same purpose?
2. What is the purpose of using `value` here `var n = value = szybkosc;`?
3. Your code does not have matching braces and proper html tags.

Just pass the `id` as the second parameter:

```
function displayResult(szybkosc, id) {
    var n = szybkosc;
    var u = n.split("|")[1];
    document.getElementById(id).innerText = ' ' + u;
}
```

The PHP Code is updated as:

```
$i = 1;
while($i < 10){
    $result = "result" . $i;
    $displayResult = "displayResult" . $i;
    echo "user number ".$i."
    <input type='radio' name='szybkosc' onclick='$displayResult(this.value)' value='$sp1[id]|1|$row[id]' />
    <input type='radio' name='szybkosc' onclick='$displayResult(this.value)' value='$sp1[id]|3|$row[id]' />
    <span id='$result'></span></br>
    <input type='radio' name='ss' value='$sp1[id]|1|$row[id]' />
    <input type='radio' name='ss' onclick='$displayResult(this.value, "result' . $i .'")' value='$sp1[id]|1|$row[id]' />";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, shouldn't be document.getElementById(result, id) instead document.getElementById(id) maybe?

Comment: No. `getElementById()` is an in built function that accepts the string representation of the id as a parameter. What error are you getting. Check the console in developer tools / Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use multiple js functions for each of the items in your php loop.
Just use this single js function and pass parameters to it accordingly:

```
function displayResult(szybkosc, id)
   var n=value=szybkosc;
   var u=n.split("|")[1]; 
   document.getElementById('result'+id).innerText = ' '+u;
}
```

And modify the php loop code that calls the js function:

```
$i = 1;
    while($i     $result = "result" . $i;
    $displayResult = "displayResult" . $i;
    echo "user number ".$i."
    input type='radio' name='szybkosc' onclick='$displayResult(this.value, '.$i.')' value='$sp1[id]|1|$row[id]' />
    input type='radio' name='szybkosc' onclick='$displayResult(this.value, '.$i.')' value='$sp1[id]|3|$row[id]' />  
   input type='radio' name='ss' value='$sp1[id]|1|$row[id]' />
   input type='radio' name='ss' onclick='$displayResult(this.value, '.$i.')' value='$sp1[id]|1|$row[id]' />";
   $i++;
}
```

By the way, your php while loop has no opening brace.